# Running powershell commands from GitLab CI

Tags: azure, powershell, gitlab-ci

I am trying to execute the following yaml from a Windows 10 machine that has been configured as runner with Powershell as the shell. I have installed Azure CLI and Azure powershell modules on the windows machine. When I execute the pipeline, it runs the Azure CLI commands. However, the Azure powershell commands were not recognized. I am able to run these commands locally on the windows machine. Any idea what is missing here?

```yaml
variables:
  DEFAULT_RG:
    description: "Default resource group to deploy the resources for testing"
    value: "newgrp"
  DEFAULT_LOCATION:
    description: "Default location of the testing resource group"
    value: "East US"
  
default:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli
  before_script:
    - az login --service-principal --username $SP_ID --password $SP_SECRET --tenant $TENANT_ID
    - az account set --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    - set -euo pipefail

stages:
  - deploy
deploy automation account and tie it with UAMI:
  stage: deploy
   
  script:
    - New-AzAutomationAccount -Location $Location -Name $automationccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup
    - Set-AzAutomationAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $automationccount -AssignUserIdentity "/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourcegroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/$userAssignedOne"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your defaults, you're using `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli` which is a Linux-based image. If you need to run Azure PowerShell commands you need to specify a windows runner. Since you are not specifying what runner to use explicitly in your `deploy automation account and tie it with UAMI` job, it'll inherit from the default to use the Linux-based Docker image.

You can either use Azure CLI equivalent for creating new automation accounts:

- [`az automation account`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/automation/account?view=azure-cli-latest)

or use a windows runner if you need to run the Azure PowerShell commands.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually I removed the Azure-CLI image and tried a windows runner. I can confirm that it picked my windows runner where I had installed both Azure CLI and Azure powershell however the the runner couldn't recognize Azure Powershell commands. You may see the yaml below :-

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. Actually I removed the Azure-CLI image and tried a windows runner. I can confirm that it picked my windows runner where I had installed both Azure CLI and Azure powershell however the the runner couldn't recognize Azure Powershell commands. You may see the yaml below :

```
build_deploy:
  stage: build_deploy
  script:
    - echo $SP_ID
    - echo $TENANT_ID
    - echo $SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    - az login --service-principal --username $SP_ID --password $SP_SECRET --tenant $TENANT_ID
    - az account set --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    - set -euo pipefail
    - New-AzAutomationAccount -Location $Location -Name $automationccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup
    - Set-AzAutomationAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $automationccount -AssignUserIdentity "/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourcegroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/$userAssignedAcc"
```